# Can I apply the required attribute to <select> fields in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, select, required

How can I check if a user has selected something from a `<select>` field in HTML?

I see `<select>` doesn't support the new `required` attribute... do I have to use JavaScript then? Or is there something I’m missing? :/

Comment: If you're interested in any level of cross-browser compatibility, you'll probably have to use JavaScript. The attribute you want is `selectedIndex`.

Comment: Per the current editor's draft of the HTML5 spec (6 Aug 2011), the select element does have a required attribute.  "The required attribute is a boolean attribute. When specified, the user will be required to select a value before submitting the form."  http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-select-element

Answer (score 582, accepted):

**Mandatory**: Have the first value empty - required works on empty values

*Prerequisites*: correct html5 DOCTYPE and a named input field

```
<select name="somename" required>
<option value="">Please select</option>
<option value="one">One</option>
</select>
```

As per [the documentation](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-select-element.html#the-select-element) (the listing and bold is mine)

> The required attribute is a boolean
>   attribute.
>   When specified, the user
>   will be required to select a value
>   before submitting the form.
>
> If a select element
>
> - has a required attribute specified,
> - does not have a multiple attribute specified,
> - and has  a display size of 1 (do not have SIZE=2 or more - omit it if not needed);
> - **and if the value 
>     of the first option element in the
>     select element's list of options (if
>     any) is the empty string** (i.e. present as `value=""`),
> - and that
>     option element's parent node is the
>     select element (and not an optgroup
>     element),
>
> then that option is the
>   select element's placeholder label
>   option.

Comment: Also, so that the user can't select the non-option once it has been selected:

<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Please Select</option>

Comment: @CoolAJ86 Works in Chrome 23, Firefox 16 and IE 10 well.

Comment: @mplungjan I know adding `aria-required="required"` on input fields does help improve support, although I'm unsure about on selects. Thoughts?

Comment: Interesting, I have not used Aria yet. Did you try? Here is more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-required_attribute

Comment: The paraphrasing of the documentation is very helpful; thanks

Comment: You can use the `:valid` css selector to apply a custom style to a select element depending on if the empty value is selected.

Comment: what does "display size of 1" mean?

Comment: Actually, it's 0 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attr-size and THAT was sucking my day

Comment: Ah yes - do NOT specify size!

Comment: Per the last comment, should this answer be edited to remove the display size 1 requirement?

Comment: That is the default - so perhaps I need to say: do NOT specify size unless it it 1 in which case omit it

Comment: A nice trick is to remove the placeholder option on focus of the select.  Of course, this would depend greatly on the nature of the form.

Comment: Notice that simply omitting the `value` attribute does not work, you have to include `value=""`.

Comment: `And if the value of the first option element is the empty string,`

Comment: How can I get an error message from this? Like other filed (input) provided.

Comment: @rajibkarmaker add the attribute `required` and the browser generates the error message for you - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input - your doctype has to be html5 compliant

Comment: Clarification on the `disabled` attribute for the placeholder option: works fine in Safari, but fails in Firefox 74 (the second option element is selected when the page is shown.)

Comment: @fbitterlich You are referring to the comment where I stated `That does not make sense... Also it will not work on several browsers `

Comment: Yes, exactly. I just think it *would* make sense to use, as you could prevent the user from selecting that item. But alas, it doesn't work (consistently.)

Answer (score 15):

The `<select>` element does support the `required` attribute, as per the spec:

- http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-select-element.html#the-select-element

Which browser doesn’t honour this?

(Of course, you have to validate on the server anyway, as you can’t guarantee that users will have JavaScript enabled.)

Comment: I am sure he just needed a value="" on the first entry - if there is no value attribute or a value on all options the required fail to trigger because the select returns an actual value

Comment: @mplungjan: *ah*, gotcha — well-spotted.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Can we still not guarantee that users will have Javascript enabled? I've only been in web development about 2 years now and I've never run into that problem.

Comment: @user137717: It’s the web. You can’t guarantee anything. You can, of course, decide that it’s not worth catering for.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it's working:

```
<select name="somename" required>
     <option value="">Please select</option>
     <option value="one">One</option>
</select>
```

you have to keep first option blank.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `selected` attribute for the option element to select a choice by default.  You can use the `required` attribute for the select element to ensure that the user selects something.

In Javascript, you can check the `selectedIndex` property to get the index of the selected option, or you can check the `value` property to get the value of the selected option.

According to the HTML5 spec, `selectedIndex` "returns the index of the first selected item, if any, or −1 if there is no selected item.  And `value` "returns the value of the first selected item, if any, or the empty string if there is no selected item."  So if selectedIndex = -1, then you know they haven't selected anything.

```
<button type="button" onclick="displaySelection()">What did I pick?</button>
<script>
    function displaySelection()
    {
        var mySelect = document.getElementById("someSelectElement");
        var mySelection = mySelect.selectedIndex;
        alert(mySelection);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @Apostle - Please stop trying to change this answer via edits. If you believe it is incorrect, feel free to leave your own answer.

Comment: @BradLarson At first I did not quite understand: the code is not a **complete** solution to the problem in this question or is an explanatory example to the last paragraph of this answer. Probably second in this case. I think better to organize this code as a snippet and show the result `-1`. Sorry, I didn't clarify in comments first.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the `value` attribute of `option` to the empty string:

```
<select name="status" required>
    <option selected disabled value="">what's your status?</option>
    <option value="code">coding</option>
    <option value="sleep">sleeping</option>
</select>
```

`select` will return the `value` of the selected `option` to the server when the user presses `submit` on the `form`. An empty `value` is the same as an empty `text` input -> raising the `required` message.

---

[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_value.asp)

> The value attribute specifies the value to be sent to a server when a form is submitted.
>
> [Example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_select_required)

Comment: This is the most perfect answer IF you try to apply `required` attribute, apply `:invalid` CSS pseudo class because it work in all browsers! The other answer that have no `required` **and** `selected` attributes in `<option>` element **with** `required` attribute in `<select>` element does not work or can't apply with CSS `:invalid`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<form action="">

<select required>

  <option selected disabled value="">choose</option>
  <option value="red">red</option>
  <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
  <option value="green">green</option>
  <option value="grey">grey</option>

</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This answer merely repeats a previous example with no additional explanation.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 2):

try this, this gonna work, I have tried this and this works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="#">
<select required>
  <option value="">None</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 1):

Make the value of first item of selection box to blank.

So when every you post the FORM you get blank value and using this way you would know that user hasn't selected anything from dropdown.

```
<select name="user_role" required>
    <option value="">-Select-</option>
    <option value="User">User</option>
    <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

first you have to assign blank value in first option.
i.e. Select here.than only required will work.

Answer (score 1):

Works perfectly fine if the first option's value is null. Explanation : The HTML5 will read a null value on button submit. If not null (value attribute), the selected value is assumed not to be null hence the validation would have worked i.e by checking if there's been data in the option tag. Therefore it will not produce the validation method. However, i guess the other side becomes clear, if the value attribute is set to null ie (value = "" ), HTML5 will detect an empty value on the first or rather the default selected option thus giving out the validation message. Thanks for asking. Happy to help. Glad to know if i did.

Answer (score -1):

In html5 you can do using the full expression:

```
<select required="required">
```

I don't know why the short expression doesn't work, but try this one.
It will solve.

Answer (score -4):

Try this

```
<select>
<option value="" style="display:none">Please select</option>
<option value="one">One</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score -5):

You can do it also dynamically with JQuery

Set required

```
$("#select1").attr('required', 'required');
```

Remove required

```
$("#select1").removeAttr('required');
```