# Make the <select> Field Required?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I apply the required attribute to <select> fields in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048710/can-i-apply-the-required-attribute-to-select-fields-in-html5)

I'm using the html5 contact form from [here](http://eightonefive.com/blog/2011/10/20/create-a-simple-html5-contact-form/) but I'm having issues trying to make the `<select>` field required. Everything else works fine, just having trouble with this and the dev hasnt responded when I asked about the field.  this is what I have

```
 <select name="package" id="package" title="Please choose a package" class="required">
    <option value="">------------------</option>
    <option value="basic">Basic</option>
    <option value="plus">Plus</option>
    <option value="premium">Premium</option>
</select>
```

What am I missing to get this working correctly?

Comment: It's easy with javascript

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Can you provide CSS, interested to see what is in "required" style. Also, are you using any javascript validation, if not you can use simple javascript validation - if(package.selectedIndex<=0) //value not selected

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287353/does-the-select-element-have-the-required-attribute

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe that the top answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048710/can-i-apply-the-required-attribute-to-select-fields-in-html5) is what you're looking for.
To quote,

> This works for me - Have the first value empty - required works on empty values.
>
> `<select required>
>   <option value="">Please select</option>
>   <option value="one">One</option>
>   </select>`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a better browser, you can try this (like in [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048710/can-i-apply-the-required-attribute-to-select-fields-in-html5) thread):

```
<select required>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="basic">Basic</option>
  <option value="plus">Plus</option>
  <option value="premium">Premium</option>
</select>
```

, but still you should use JavaScript because not a lot of people have browsers that support HTML5 `required` attribute. It's not supported by IE and Safari.

Comment: If You will put `aria-required="true"` it will work on Safari, Beside webside have to check on server side if that field has been set so it's just a mater of taste to check it in JS. Personally i think that users using ie should blame themselves :)

Answer (score 0):

check this: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/select.html

global attributes
    Any attributes permitted globally.

1. name = string

   The name part of the name/value pair associated with this element for the purposes of form submission.
2. disabled = "disabled" or "" (empty string) or empty

   Specifies that the element represents a disabled control.
3. form = ID reference NEW

   The value of the id attribute on the form with which to associate the element.
4. size = positive integer

   The number of options to show to the user.
5. multiple = "multiple" or "" (empty string) or empty

   If present, indicates that its select element represents a control for selecting zero or more options from a list of options.
   If not present, indicates that its select element represents a control for selecting a single option from a list of options.
6. autofocus = "autofocus" or "" (empty string) or empty

   Specifies that the element represents a control to which a UA is meant to give focus as soon as the document is loaded.
7. `required = "required" or ""` (empty string) or empty

   Specifies that the element is a required part of form submission.

so you require a `required = "required"` attribute to your `<select>`