# "REQUIRED" attributes not working in PHP HTML

Tags: php, html

I was trying to add a validation for an Empty Field. If field is empty, form will not be submitted. But my "required" attributes not working.

```
Birthdate: 
<select name="month" required>
<option value="0" required>Select Month</option>
    <?php
        for( $m = 1; $m <= 12; $m++ )
            {
                $num = str_pad( $m, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT );
                $month = date( 'F', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $m + 1, 0, 0 ) );?>
                <option value="<?php echo $num;?>"><?php echo $month; ?></option>
                <?php
            }
    ?>
    </select>

</select>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the select element have the required attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287353/does-the-select-element-have-the-required-attribute)

Comment: @SvenEberth I was trying to add a validation. If field is empty,  form will not be submitted:

Comment: Did you read the accepted answer from the link @SvenEberth posted? Your first `value` should be empty for `required` to work

Comment: Hello @ace_mbj you have to set one `<option>` tag value to empty because there is no empty `<option>` is there that's why required fails and the selected value is send to you backend by setting `<option value="">` it validate properly

Answer (score 0):

`<option>` does not need 'required', only in `<select>` is enough. if you want to get first one as default use 'selected' instead of 'required'.

Answer (score 0):

Option tag does not have required attribute.

```
<select name="month" required>
<option value="0">Select Month</option>
    <?php
        for( $m = 1; $m <= 12; $m++ )
            {
                $num = str_pad( $m, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT );
                $month = date( 'F', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $m + 1, 0, 0 ) );?>
                <option value="<?php echo $num;?>"><?php echo $month; ?></option>
                <?php
            }
    ?>
</select>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Answer (score 0):

You could unset value in the first option. Example:

```
<select name="month" required>
      <option value="" required>Select Month</option>
      <option value="1">January</option>
      <option value="2">February</option>
      <option value="3">March</option>
      <option value="4">...</option>
</select>
```