# How to create text curve effect using web programming. preferring (c#, vb javascript or jquery)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, css

What I am really stuck with, is to create word art type effects dynamically from the user's text input. I have googled around but could not find anything.

The site that is currently using it is

http://www.customink.com/lab/...
 Please checkout its add text>>effects

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: They send the request to the server `<img id="img_view_1_icon_TEXT_0" class=" created_at-1336715722254 resize" src="../text/gen?op[txt]=Howdy%20Doody&amp;op[fnt]=Impact01&amp;op[ht]=20&amp;op[sf]=20&amp;op[r]=0&amp;op[g]=0&amp;op[b]=0&amp;op[cf]=false&amp;op[as]=0&amp;op[st]=0&amp;op[s_r]=0&amp;op[s_g]=0&amp;op[s_b]=0&amp;op[ef]=arch&amp;op[efs]=5.0&amp;op[ro]=0&amp;op[a]=left">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Alternative

http://www.boutell.com/gd/

Comment: thanks for your help but what i really want is word art type of effects that is generated when the user inputs some text.

Presently i am following the asp.net c# model and trying to get it using System.Drawing. IF there is any way please help me out
If i was not clear before i am sorry for that

Comment: YW. I hope whoever downvoted will reconsider and next time comment as to why it was downvoted in the first place.

Comment: @mplungjan - it's likely because your answer is just a link to elsewhere, and doesn't actually provide anything to answer the question here. It would be much more useful if you quoted some of the relevant info directly in your answer.

Comment: Thanks, I however think a link to the most used effects library is a good enough answer to a very vague question. Anyway, we are 3 years further down the line, and I still believe it is a simple courtesy to comment on a downvote. For example I have two inexplicable downvotes [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048710/can-i-apply-the-required-attribute-to-select-fields-in-html5/6048891#6048891)