# Javascript onclick confirm not working with "required" tag HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, submit

I have a `<select>` list written in HTML and it's marked with the `<required>` tag for validation. Like this `<select name="users" width="200" size="11" style="outline:none" required>`

And a submit button for the form `<input type="submit" onclick="return confirm(\Are you sure to disable this user?\'); value="Disable user" formaction="disableuser">`

But when I submit the form without selecting a user from the list it still fires the confirm pop-up, even nothing is selected. I'm stuck with this, can somebody help me? Thanks.

Comment: validate using javascript. don't rely on browser features or adherance to standards... IE will allways throw a wrench in the works, or another browser.

Comment: Make sure that the select and the submit button are enclosed in a form

Comment: Yes, I have those in a form. But still doesn't work.

Comment: The required attribute is supported in Internet Explorer 10, Firefox, Opera, and Chrome.

See this example: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Comment: @VinhNT I'm using IE11, Firefox and Chrome for my development. All are the newest versions. But I will look to use javascript validation if possible.

Comment: I see a typo as in <input type="submit" onclick="return confirm(\Are you sure to disable this user?\'); value="Disable user" formaction="disableuser">

it should be <input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to disable this user?');" value="Disable user" formaction="disableuser">

Comment: onclick="return confirm('are ...?');"

Comment: Tested this (with typos fixed) on Chrome, Firefox, IE – they all issue a browser-generated message instead of triggering the `onclick` handler. It’s different if you have `size="1"`. Please check that the code in the question matches your real code (and post code as sent to browser, rather than content of a .php file).

Comment: Those slashes are needed there otherwise it won't work (just tested it). My code in the question matches my real code so no typos. Why it's different with the `size` tag?

Comment: The “slashes” (backslashes, “\”) relate to PHP, not HTML. Please post the actual HTML code as received by a browser, and provide code that actually reproduces the problem. The code in the question is incomplete, and when completed to a minimal document does *not* reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
function Submit() {
    if(//check whether a user is selected)
    {
       var r = confirm("Are you sure to disable this user?");
       if (r == true) {
           //do what ever you need
       }
       else {
        return;
       }
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Please select a user!!!');
    }
}
```

Invoke Submit() on onclick of submit button...

Comment: This does not address the question (why the `required` attribute does not work).

Comment: After a few tries it finally works. I think this is better then the `<required>` tag, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the code actually has `size="1"` instead of `size="11"`, because with the latter, the problem does not arise (on modern browsers). For `size=1`, the first option is interpreted as selected, so the element satisfies the requiredness constraint even when the user has not made any selection. To avoid this, insert a dummy option with an empty value. It is customary to use it in a placeholder-like manner:

```
<select name="users" width="200" size="1" style="outline:none" required>
<option value="">Select a user:
<option>foo
<option>bar
</select>
```

The issue is explained in detail at [Can I apply the required attribute to <select> fields in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048710/can-i-apply-the-required-attribute-to-select-fields-in-html5)

As always, you should not rely on any client-side checks; they are for user comfort, not for security. The processing of the form data server-side should be based on the assumption that the user is a malevolent hacker who uses a modified version of your form. In particular, in this case, the value of `users` can be literally anything.

Comment: My select list is not a dropdown menu, that's why i'm using `size="11"`. The list is a normal one like a `<li>` list but then it is selectable.