# Check if "value" attribute is present in IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

In IE > 7 it can be done by checking if `value` exists in the `attributes` collection or using `getAttribute()` which returns null, but in IE <= 7, this collection returns all the supported attributes and `getAttribute()` returns an empty string, the same as `element.value`.

[attributes](http://help.dottoro.com/ljpnafvg.php)
[getAttribute()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Any hints?

Comment: Why on earth do you want the `value` attribute instead of the `value` property?

Comment: Form polyfill, specifically a select with required: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6048891/458093. If the first option has no "value" attribute but has text content, it validates, but if it has a "value" attribute with an empty string, it doesn't validate. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

In IE6/7, try checking for the attribute like this:

`element["value"] !== undefined`

Please see the first answer to this code review question for more details: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/10131/will-this-test-to-check-if-an-element-has-an-attribute-work

Comment: Did you try the routine mentioned in the post I linked to? Also, did you use `!==` or just `!=`?

Comment: Which routine? `el.value` returns an empty string, and yes, with strict comparator `!==`

Comment: If `el.value` is undefined, then that means that the value attribute is not present. I thought this is the behaviour you are after?

Comment: The function I am referring to is `return tag.hasAttribute ? tag.hasAttribute(attrName) : tag[attrName] !== undefined;`. I would also use IE7's debugging tools to inspect the element and verify that the attribute is not present in the DOM. Something else could be possibly creating this attribute in the background.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61225/discussion-between-peter-and-gabriel-llamas).