# How to make a Bootstrap dropdown required?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

So, I've got following code for a dropdown box made with bootstrap:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button id="landKapitein" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">Land
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">België/Belgique</a></li>
        <li><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Deutschland</a></li>
        <li><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">France</a></li>
        <li><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Nederland</a></li>
        <li><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">United Kingdom</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Now I want to make it required to select something from this dropdown box before you can continue on. I've already done this for textboxes and radio buttons by just adding *required* to the  tag, but I don't have a tag like that here, so how do I do this then?

Comment: Instead of using the `select` element as @samuelms suggested, did you find another solution?

Answer (score 40):

If we just put required in select tag and  `<option value="">None</option>` in the option it will work for validation. I have refer this [page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_select_required://).

It works for selection must be made among provided value.

But I would like to know how to write custom validation message coming by default like this message.? [image]

```
 <form action="demo_form.asp">
    <select required>
      <option value="">None</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Above code works fine for validation like "Selecting an item in the list before submit".

Comment: I'm unsure what Bootstrap version you're using but if you put "required" in your 'select' and then put <option value="">None</option> in your dropdown, you will get what you are asking for.

Answer (score 4):

Use this code if you want to required Bootstrap drop down select

```
<select id='terms' class='form-control' required>
    <option selected disabled>Select </option>
    <option value="Y">Yes</option>
    <option value="N">No</option>
</select>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value

Answer (score 2):

Could you just use a [select element](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls) instead and apply required to its tag?

```
<select class="form-control" required>
    <option>België/Belgique</option>
    <option>Deutschland</option>
    <option>France</option>
    <option>Nederland</option>
    <option>United Kingdom</option>
</select>
```

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6048891/1647315) in particular.

Comment: You have to change the styling of the `select` element in order to get the same styling as the bootstrap's way of using a button and a list. Which might not be what you want to do.

Comment: If one wants to use ui.bootstrap.dropdown then select, option is a no go. Can it be done together with ui.bootstrap.dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

In CSS:

```css
.btn.btn-default.dropdown-toggle.is-invalid {
  border-color: #dc3545;
}
```

In HTML:

```html
<input type="hidden" class="form-control"  name="idType" required />
<div class="btn-group">
    <button id="landKapitein" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">Land
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">België/Belgique</a></li>
        <li><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Deutschland</a></li>
        <li><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">France</a></li>
        <li><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Nederland</a></li>
        <li><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">United Kingdom</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

In JavaScript: set the value of the input field on selecting the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-control" required="required">
 <option>A</option>
 <option>A</option>
 <option>A</option>
</select>
```

please set required =  "required" in your selector