# Codeigniter dropdown validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my code:

```
        <div class="two-columns">
            <div class="col-half">
                <label for="city">Città</label>
                <input type="text" name="city" class="required">
            </div>
            <div class="col-half">
                <label for="province">Provincia</label><br>
                <select name="province" class="required">
                    <option value="">Seleziona la provincia</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

As you can see I put the "class required" in the dropdown because the user must choose a value. All works fine but I cannot see the alert message if I miss to select an item from the dropdown; the form is not sent, correct, but the alert is not shown. Any hints?

Comment: what is that class="required"? isn't it required attribute??

Comment: kindly post your controller where you set_rules for validation in codeigniter. and class = requried doesn't mean anything actually its required paramter in frontend to make a field required. so just post your controller where you pass these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add like this `class='required'` it will not do any kind of `validation`.

- The `class` attribute is mostly used to point to a class in a style
  sheet. However, it can also be used by a JavaScript (via the HTML
  DOM) to make changes to HTML elements with a specified class.

If you want to do validation you can do it in different ways.

- By Using **HTML5** `required` attribute

  For Ex : `<select name="" required>`
- Server side form validation in `codeigniter`.
  Dont forgot to include validation libraray 
  `$this->load->library('form_validation');`

  For Ex : `$this->form_validation->set_rules("province","province","required")`
- Finally you can use `jquery` or `javascript` validation

  Hope it will help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just have it as

```
<select name="province" required>
    <option value="">Seleziona la provincia</option>
</select>
```

Here's a link to a helpful stackoverflow post about it:

[Can I apply the required attribute to <select> fields in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048710/can-i-apply-the-required-attribute-to-select-fields-in-html5/6048891#6048891)