# Hiding/Disabling the submit button for an Ajax form until a selection is made from dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to hide (or disable) the submit button for an Ajax form, until a selection has been made from a DropDownList (@Html.DropDownList)

the form looks like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("RoleAddToUser", "Roles", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "middle_column", HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { id = "RoleAddToUserForm" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<p>
    User : @Html.DropDownList("UserName", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Users, "Select ...")
    Role : @Html.DropDownList("RoleName", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Roles, "Select ...")
</p>
<input type="button" name="SubmitBtn1" value="Send" onclick="$('#RoleAddToUserForm').submit(); " />
}
```

I assume that there is a way to detect that a value other than "select..." (the default one) has been chosen, and then to enable/show the submit button, using Javascript.

I also understand that this is probably trivial for most Js fans, but i dont normally work with cshtml or javascript, and this is very frustrating lol

If it helps, the file in question is cshtml from an mvc program.

Comment: are you using any other javascript libraries that support binding? ie. Angular?

Comment: The `"select.."` option has a `null` value so you can just use `if ($('#UserName).val()) {...}` but this is a poor UI design. You should be using client side validation to prevent the form submitting and display the appropriate error messages

Comment: @StephenMuecke this is all client side

Comment: @Johan, What do you think **client** side validation is :)

Comment: @Johan yes, we are using Angular and a few more i think :/

Comment: @StephenMuecke validation happening in the browser...

Comment: @WillGrey then you can use angulars binding to enable/disable the button

Answer (score 1):

use change event to detect value

```
$("select").on("change",function(){
if($(this).val()){
$("input[name='SubmitBtn1']").prop("disabled",false);
}
esle{
$("input[name='SubmitBtn1']").prop("disabled",true);
}
});
```

Comment: The option will never have a value of `'Select ...'` so this will always fail.

Comment: i am assuming from question description "I assume that there is a way to detect that a value other than "select..." "

Comment: Yes but OP want the button disabled if the 'Select ...' option is selected (and you have also indicated that in your code so this wont work (hint: the `.val()` is `null`, not `'Select ...'`)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/farhanbaloch/bba6f9kz/ its working, i might missing something from requirement. if yes then please guide me

Comment: That's because you have hard coded the value in the fiddle. The `DropDownList()` method OP is using creates the first option as `<option value>select...</option>` (not `value="select..."`)

Comment: would != null have the same effect?

Comment: That will work, but easier to just use `if ($('#UserName).val())` as I noted in my comments to the question.

Comment: so, in this instance, does the $("select") refer to the name of the dropdownlist?

Comment: not name but all selects on page, you can place id or class here too instead of select

Comment: You will need to use the `id` attributes to identify each select and test both because `$('select').val()` will only ever get the value of the first one (but please don't do this)

Comment: @stephen if we are using change event with $(this) then isn't point to drop down with value changed?

Comment: You are right about needing to check both of the selects in the form before activating the button.
And ive seen suggestions on other pages about checking if the form is valid before submitting, but isnt that just the same thing?
or is there a function for that which i dont know about?

Comment: @WillGrey If you include `@Html.ValidationMesageFor()` for each of your properties and those 2 properties are decorated with the `[Required]` attribute and client side validation is enabled. then if the user clicks the submit button, the form will not be submitted and error messages will be displayed if either of the `"select..."` options are selected, giving immediate feedback to the user.

Comment: @stephen you are possible talking about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048710/can-i-apply-the-required-attribute-to-select-fields-in-html5. But I think [required] will not work with select. I think this should be like this, on change event of "select" check both selects if there ae not null.

Comment: @Farhan, Of course the `[Required]` attribute works with select. Because the `"select..."` option has a `null` value, it will be  invalid so a validation error is generated by `jquery.validate.js`. From the link in your last comment, I assume your confusing the HTML `required` attribute with MVC validation

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for the info. I am not aware with asp.net so no idea what would be the output. This is all from my side. I must insist you to  add new answer.

Comment: @Farhan, Your answer is now fine and resolves OP's question (its just that IMHO, OP is going about it the right way)

Answer (score 1):

Add `disabled="disabled"` attribute to the button. So that it will be disabled. When you want to enable it, use jQuery to enable `$('#id').removeAttr('disabled')`

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are more graceful ways to go about this, but this seems to work:

I added **id="SubmitBtn1" style="display:none"**  to the button then used

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//On change
$('#UserName').change(
function checkValue() {

    //Check if the dropdownlist's value is equal to the default
    if ($('#UserName').val() == "") {

        //if it is, hide it/keep hidden            
        hide_item('SubmitBtn1');

        return
    }

    //otherwise show it
    show_item('SubmitBtn1');

});


function show_item(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);

    el.style.display = 'inline-block';

};

function hide_item(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);

    el.style.display = 'none';

};

</script>
```

Feedback?