# select option input required using css class

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can we make select option html input required without touching html tags by using css/javascript code?

```
<form action="?" method="post">
    <select class='css-class'>
        <option value=''>choose</option>
        <option value='1' data-key='1'>one</option>
        <option value='2' data-key='2'>two</option>   
        <input type="submit"/>
    </select>
</form>
```

css

```
.css-class select option{
    /* anything here to make it required */
}
```

I don't mind using javascript

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t27au3oL/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JS by using the [`required` property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_required.asp). It's just like the `required` attribute that's on tags, but it's a JS property instead of a HTML attribute.

I added another `<select>` to demonstrate. Try submitting only the second `<select>` and you'll see it'll require `<select class="css-class">` to be submitted.

---

```js
document.querySelector('.css-class').required = true;
```

```html
<form action="?" method="post">
  <select class='css-class'>
    <option value=''>choose</option>
    <option value='1' data-key='1'>one</option>
    <option value='2' data-key='2'>two</option>
    <input type="submit" />
  </select>

  <select class='css-id'>
    <option value=''>choose</option>
    <option value='1' data-key='1'>one</option>
    <option value='2' data-key='2'>two</option>
    <input type="submit" />
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible with just css as this is just for styling content.

Could this answer provide a solution for you: [Can I apply the required attribute to <select> fields in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048710/can-i-apply-the-required-attribute-to-select-fields-in-html5)

The markup they suggest:

```
<select required>
<option value="">Please select</option>
<option value="one">One</option>
</select>
```