# Html option selected disabled cause select required not working

Tags: html

```
<select name="status" required>
<option selected disabled>status</option>
```

I have set required attribute in html select.

My first option set selected disabled for display text.

However it will cause required attribute not working.

anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: required will not working in lower versions of ie9 and safari. Are you using any of these browsers!?

Comment: because 1st option auto select, so select required no longer to work

Comment: not browser issue, my problem is 1st display option auto select cause required not working

Comment: look into the accepted answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048710/can-i-apply-the-required-attribute-to-select-fields-in-html5 Hope it helps!

Comment: <option value=""> the first option is to be kept blank for select required to work! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I apply the required attribute to <select> fields in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048710/can-i-apply-the-required-attribute-to-select-fields-in-html5)

Comment: @BenjaminW did my answer solve the issue for you?

Answer (score 51):

**Set `<option>`'s `value` to empty string (`''`).**

### Updated Code

```
<select name="status" required>
    <option selected disabled value="">status</option>
    <!-- Additional options here (at least one should not be disabled) -->
</select>
```

### Explanation

`select` will return the `value` of the selected `option` to the server when the user presses `submit` on the `form`. An empty `value` is the same as an empty `text` input → raising the `required` message.

---

### More info ([w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_value.asp))

> The value attribute specifies the value to be sent to a server when a form is submitted.

#### Example

```js
document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const status = e.target[0].value;
  console.log(`Your status is: "${status}"`);
 }
```

```html
<form>
  <select name="status" required>
    <option selected disabled value="">Select a status...</option>
    <option value="Good">Good</option>
    <option value="Bad">Bad</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Comment: Thanks. It really work for this `<option disabled selected value="">Choose the Class</option>`

Comment: As a bonus, adding the hidden attribute to your list removes the visibility of the placeholder option from the dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

To step one further:
The problem with the `disabled` attribute on the selected option element is that the container `<select>` element will also treated as disabled, and this leads to this select element's value will not being posted to the server at all, and JavaScript `new FormData()` constructor also omit it.

To solve this, change the disabled to `readonly`. And add the `hidden` attribute also, so the selected option will not appear in the dropdown menu. With setting it's value to "" (falsy), the input validator prevents form submitting with a validation report, even without JavaScript.
This solution also solves the problem of the FormData constructor and you will also be able to easily find that this input has an invalid value with the Constraint Validation API's `selectElement.checkValidity()` method.

```
<form>
  <select name="status" required>
    <option value="" hidden readonly selected>I am a placeholder...</option>
    <option value="Good">Good</option>
    <option value="Bad">Bad</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: hidden, was really helpful