# Validate select box with own custom message and rule in Jquery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, laravel-5.4

When i am using jquery validation plugin it didnot work correctly for my dropdown box..

My html code is

```
<select class="control-select form-control" name="job_title" id="job_title" >
  <option value="Select Role">-- Select Role--</option>                              
  <option value="Admin" {{ ($admin->job_title=="Admin") ? "selected" : "" }}>Admin</option>
  <option value="Subadmin" {{ ($admin->job_title=="Subadmin") ? "selected" : "" }}>Subadmin</option>
  <option value="Superadmin" {{ ($admin->job_title=="Superadmin") ? "selected" : "" }}>Superadmin</option>
</select>
```

And inside jquery validation rule i gave like this

```
"job_title": {
    required: true
},
```

but is didnot worked so whats the alternate way to make select box as required field

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_required.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I apply the required attribute to <select> fields in HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048710/can-i-apply-the-required-attribute-to-select-fields-in-html5)

Comment: @Rodrane no i am using jquery validation plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to replace  `value="Select Role"`  with `value=""` like below:-

Example:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#signupForm").validate({
    rules: {
      "job_title": {
        required: true
      },
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="signupForm">
<select class="control-select form-control" name="job_title" id="job_title">
  <option value="">-- Select Role--</option>                              
  <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
  <option value="Subadmin">Subadmin</option>
  <option value="Superadmin">Superadmin</option>
</select>
<input type ="submit" value = "click me">
</form>
```

Reference taken:- [Can I apply the required attribute to <select> fields in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048710/can-i-apply-the-required-attribute-to-select-fields-in-html5)

Comment: Karthiga  i have added an example that how's it going to work.Thanks

Comment: yes it worked ..i included jquery.min.js and jquery.validate.js after i added what you gave it working fine may be the version problem

Comment: @Karthiga  glad to help you.:):)..Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is working perfect,the issue is in your html, check this line:

```
<option value="Select Role">-- Select Role--</option>
```

To validate dropdown using validation plugin, you have to pass the first dropdown value as blank like:

```
<option value="">-- Select Role--</option>
```

Try this, it will solve your problem.

**Explanation:** `require` validation will check for `value` attribute, but in your case the value is there `value="Select Role"`, so make the first dropdown value blank.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cubttgow/24/)

Comment: thank you but when i make the first value as blank option also it doesnot show the error message

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
$("form").validate({
  rules: {
  job_title: { valueNotEquals: "default" }
  },
  messages: {
  job_title: { valueNotEquals: "Please select field" }
  }  
});
```