# Required to make a selection from a drop down

Tags: html

Is it possible to force/require a user to make a selection from a drop down menu?

I am thinking something like the below, but it still takes the first value "Volvo".

By default "Volvo" is selected. What I want is for the browser to know that the user has to make a selection and not to accept the auto default value.

```
< form action="" > 
< select name="cars" required>
< option value="volvo">Choose a Car Name</option >
< option value="volvo">Volvo</option >
< option value="saab">Saab</option >
< option value="fiat">Fiat</option >
< option value="audi">Audi</option >
< /select >
< /form >
```

In my case, say the first option value as "Choose a Car Name" followed by 4 car names. "Choose a Car Name" will be displayed right across the drop down field. Even after making it as  required field, it will choose the default value as "Choose a Car Name" instead of the real car name values.

The user needs to choose a car name and only then he should be able to submit

Comment: @David - I have updated my qn. Please let me know if this is clear now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I apply the required attribute to <select> fields in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048710/can-i-apply-the-required-attribute-to-select-fields-in-html5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You absolutely can do that by changing value of option "Choose a care name" to ""

Something may look like this:

```
 <option value="">Choose a Car Name</option >
```

because `<select required>` makes sure the value of `<option>` is not nil.