# how to make subcategory required with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hello everyone i need help.

i need first selected must be select model type and must be required ?

how to make id="subcategory" required ?

required for id="subcategory" not working why ?

```
<select id="category" required>
    <option value="">select model type</option>
    <option class="Volvo" value="1">Volvo</option>
    <option class="Saab" value="2">Saab</option>
    <option class="Opel" value="3">Opel</option>
    <option class="Audi" value="4">Audi</option>
</select> 
 <select id="subcategory">
  <optgroup class="Volvo">
    <option value="">select model type</option>
    <option value="44">XC60</option>
    <option value="55">XC90</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup class="Saab">
    <option value="">select model type</option>
    <option value="66">Saab 9XX</option>
    <option value="77">Saab Aero-X</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup class="Opel">
    <option value="">select model type</option>
    <option value="88">Corsa A</option>
    <option value="99">Corsa B</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup class="Audi">
    <option value="">select model type</option>
    <option value="616">Audi A4</option>
    <option value="717">Audi A8</option>
  </optgroup>
</select> 




  <script>
$('#subcategory').find('optgroup').hide(); // initialize
$('#category').change(function() {
 var $cat = $(this).find('option:selected');
 var $subCat = $('#subcategory').find('.' + $cat.attr('class'));
 $('#subcategory').find('optgroup').not("'"+ '.' + $cat.attr('class') + "'").hide(); // hide other optgroup
 $subCat.show();
 $subCat.find('option').first().attr('selected', 'selected');
});
    </script>
```

Comment: "*`required` for `id="subcategory"` not working why?*" - because you're not setting, or updating, the `required` property in your jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea on where I updated slightly the second select to make the `select mode type` outside the `optgroup`. You will see that you won't be able to click on send until you select both values.

You can refer to this link to understand my changes:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6048891/8620333

```js
$('#subcategory').find('optgroup').hide(); // initialize
$('#category').change(function() {
  var $cat = $(this).find('option:selected');
  var $subCat = $('#subcategory').find('.' + $cat.attr('class'));
  $('#subcategory').find('optgroup').not("." + $cat.attr('class')).hide(); 
  $subCat.show();
  $('#subcategory option').removeAttr('selected');
  $('#subcategory > option').attr('selected', 'selected');
  //adding this will make it required
  $('#subcategory').attr('required','required')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<select id="category" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>select model type</option>
    <option class="Volvo" value="1">Volvo</option>
    <option class="Saab" value="2">Saab</option>
    <option class="Opel" value="3">Opel</option>
    <option class="Audi" value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
<select id="subcategory">
  <option value="">select model type</option>
  <optgroup class="Volvo">
    <option value="44">XC60</option>
    <option value="55">XC90</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup class="Saab">
    <option value="66">Saab 9XX</option>
    <option value="77">Saab Aero-X</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup class="Opel">
    <option value="88">Corsa A</option>
    <option value="99">Corsa B</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup class="Audi">
    <option value="616">Audi A4</option>
    <option value="717">Audi A8</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Comment: this code not working property. when select category and subcategory and again change category, subcategory not hidding stays old category how to fix ?

Comment: @ZuraKushitashvili are you sure ? do you see this behavior in the snippet here ? as it works fine for me here

Comment: sorry but we have one problem. when select category and refresh browser page subcategory not required any more. how to fix this problem ?