# how to make required select statement even with disabled, selected option

Tags: html, jsp

```
<form action="/xyz.jsp">
<select required>
  <option selected disabled hidden>Select one of your active items...</option>
  <option value="">None</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

The issue here is, when I specify `require` it does not act properly because the first field is selected.. it ends up producing `NULL` instead of actually requiring user to enter a choice...

Anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I apply the required attribute to <select> fields in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048710/can-i-apply-the-required-attribute-to-select-fields-in-html5)

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have to make the first option value the empty string. You will have to come with another value for your "none" option.

See also [Can I apply the required attribute to <select> fields in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048710/can-i-apply-the-required-attribute-to-select-fields-in-html5#6048891)

This is pure HTML.

```
<form action="/xyz.jsp">
<select required>
  <option value="" selected hidden>Select one of your active items...</option>
  <option value="none">None</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```